# Getting "Error running Gradle" in step "resolving dependancies" when I try to execute a flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I suspect the proxy setting is not set correctly, or I might be wrong, please help me out here. I'm working under a corporate network and using a VPN.

**Error details below:**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\flutter_workspace\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
               > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.9.14] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
  Command: D:\flutter_workspace\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally finally figured out what I was missing, I had to set the Proxy in `gradle.properties` file as directed in [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#gradle-plugin). For some reason, setting up the proxy in Android Studio alone didn't work.

**Updated `gradle.properties` file:**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

PS: Thanks @Taio for your efforts. I appreciate them

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection and make sure it is stable. Gradle is trying to connect to the internet to get resources and is unable to. 
In this case I would suggest turning off the vpn and waiting for the build process to go on with a normal internet connection then after build you can continue using the vpn

Comment: I can download the files when I try to access them from the browser. Should I configure proxy for Git or something? Like I have already mentioned I'm running behind a corporate network with VPN

Comment: What IDE are you using

Comment: I'm using Android studio and the proxy setting is set to auto detect. I tried setting it manually as well but didn't work.

Comment: How did the error come up. Had you done a successful build before and had you been on this same network

Comment: You have never done a successful build of a flutter app while on the network?